# Matplotlib One plot side with multiple subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot some graphs, I want it to look like that, and do it in python.

I tried many things but it looks way uglier than what I want to achieve, any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`add_grid_spec()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html?highlight=add_gridspec#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_gridspec), [`add_subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html?highlight=add_subplot#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot), and [`subgridspec()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.SubplotSpec.html?highlight=subgridspec#matplotlib.gridspec.SubplotSpec.subgridspec). *(`matplotlib.__version__` >= `'3.5.0'`)*

```
# Please Update matplotlib
# !pip install matplotlib --upgrade

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
outer = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=1, ncols=2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(outer[0, 0])

inner = outer[0, 1].subgridspec(ncols=2, nrows=2, wspace=0.5)
ax2 = inner.subplots()


ax1.plot(range(10), 'r')
ax2[0,0].plot(range(20), 'g')
ax2[0,1].plot(range(10), 'r')
ax2[1,0].plot(range(5), 'b')
ax2[1,1].plot(range(10), 'y')
    
    
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this code throws this error: 'GridSpecFromSubplotSpec' object has no attribute 'subplots'

Comment: @DemetreDzmanashvili, what is your matplotlib version? check with these two lines : `import matplotlib` and `matplotlib.__version__`

Comment: the version is 3.2.2.

Comment: @DemetreDzmanashvili, update matplotlib with this : `!pip install matplotlib --upgrade` before run again restart your kernel

Answer (score 2):

you can use a grid try to follow this pattern

```py
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = GridSpec(4, 4, figure=fig)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, :2])
# identical to ax1 = plt.subplot(gs.new_subplotspec((0, 0), colspan=3))
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:2, 2])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:2, 3])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:, 2])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:, 3])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps easier than the above (with relatively modern matplotlib):

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    [['A', 'b', 'c'],
     ['A', 'd', 'e']],
    gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[2, 1, 1]},
    constrained_layout=True
)
```

Note that when 3.6 gets released, you can just do:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    [['A', 'b', 'c'],
     ['A', 'd', 'e']],
    width_ratios=[2, 1, 1],
    constrained_layout=True
)
```